# Circuitpython for (1x4) matrix keypad

Tags: python, adafruit, keypad

I am still learning about Circuitpython and I have trouble working with a keypad. So I have a Feather M4 Express board(FM4E) and (1x4) Matrix keypad. The (1x4) Matrix keypad has 5 pins where I think four pins are for the numbers on the keypad (1 till 4) and the fifth pin is connected to the power. [(FM4E image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVQT.png) [keypad image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF6Ui.png) So I connected all four pins to pin A0, A1, A2, and A3 on the FM4E board.
I want to read the keys pressed on the keypad and I am unable to do so. I tried testing the keypad by using if statements and print the number if each button is pressed.

I noticed that it prints multiple times if press one button and sometimes it overlaps with the other keys. For example, I press '2' on the keypad, it prints '2' and'3'.

Is there a better approach to read the key once when the one button on the keypad is pressed?

Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the issues with button 3 being registered when you're pressing button 2. But when it comes to the multiple times it has to do with the buttons not being perfect switches. Whenever you press a button it actually [actuates a bunch of times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) (basically bouncing before the connection is set).

There seems to be a [debouncing library](https://learn.adafruit.com/debouncer-library-python-circuitpython-buttons-sensors/basic-debouncing) for circuit python that you could try out.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a key matrix and have found that there are two main problems with them. Ghosting in which your dealing with and Bouncing.
Ghosting is when one key is pressed and other keys will get mixed in. Easily fixed with a diode on each key.

[Power in->[key]>-Diode-> ground]
This site has a better discription:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66691/which-kind-of-diodes-i-should-use-in-buttons-keys-matrix-input-making-gaming-k

this can be done for comlumes or rows, but make sure to stick all to one or the other as its over kill and can cause issues.

Debouncing can be done in code (still working that out myself) or with a semi complicated physical setup like the diodes ^^
Best to just stick to code when you can lol.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).